# Allow guests to use WP Customizer but disable save button

Tags: customization, users, theme-customizer

I've seen in some WP demo themes that developers let users to see a theme customizer (allowing to try the customizations) disabling the save button as well.

So the question is how to do that in a WordPress installation?

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess it's that the save button is enabled/disabled according to the user role.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://greenthe.me/2013/10/gt-customizer-preview-1-04/